# mailx with uuencode is secured or not, if not what is secured way

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh

Sending email in unix with uuencode and mailx is secured ?
i am sending mail with csv attachment like below

```
(echo "attachment name"; uuencode csvfilepath csvfilename) |
    mailx -s "attachment name" -r frommailID tomailids
```

if not secured please suggest the secured way.

Comment: How do you mean "secure"?  The `uuencode` program just makes it "binary safe" (UUCP safe).  There is no encryption, if that's what you mean by safe.

Comment: uuencode only *obscures* text and secures nothing.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: that attached csv has sensitive data, so want to confirm that the mail will read only by recipients only... no other intruders can read.... so will mailx ensures this..?

Comment: Nope.  The name `mailx` is a bit misleading.  It's meant to distinguish between /bin/mail and Berkeley mail on System V systems.  You'll have to use some form of encryption.  Your system might have `crypt`.  It's weak, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data securely through email, so that you are certain that only the recipient can read the contents, you need to encrypt the data.

There are several tools available for this, but `uuencode` is not one of them since anyone with a `uudecode` command could decode the encoded content.

Personally, I'm using GnuPG, which would be able to encrypt a file from a script, either by using the recipient's public GnuPG key, or by using a symmetric cipher.

This is an example of an encrypted GnuPG message (created with `gpg2 --symmetric --armour`):

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----                                     

jA0EBwMCyfiq33FFUExg0lEBx/7bIHVdo3B4eHB5HYMJLmNpv8SM8j+rW7et65l3
DiTZIRxhhdQMfdKcMyhGUb1i9auvhX9Myzt94LIxjqLBxhh0vC/BlMhEOzyKh2bS
NjI=                                                            
=hrtj                                                           
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Decrypt it with `gpg2 --decrypt`.  The password is `hello`, by the way.